# JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.jdbcSession is not visible

Tags: java, spring, html, spring-mvc, spring-session

My program is using [Spring Session](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#httpsession-jdbc) xml based configuration and I using [JdbcOperationsSessionRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#api-jdbcoperationssessionrepository) to implement my session. The [JdbcOperationsSessionRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#api-jdbcoperationssessionrepository) library is using JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.JdbcSession and how can I set the session attributes?

```
package sessioncontrol.page;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.session.Session;
import org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository;
import org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.JdbcSession;
import org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.EnableJdbcHttpSession;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

@Log4j2
@Controller
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
public class SessionControl {
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    private JdbcOperationsSessionRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value="flpage", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showPage(Model model) {
        repository = new JdbcOperationsSessionRepository(jdbcTemplate, transactionManager);
        repository.setTableName("test.spring_session");
        repository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(120);
        JdbcSession session = repository.createSession();
        session.setAttribute("ATTR_USER", "rwinch");
        repository.save(session);

        return "flpage";
    }
}
```

It show me import `org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.JdbcSession;` is **not visible** so how can I use the inner class set attribute method properly? I really stuck here.

Thanks in advance, any comment is appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you should use an interface (either `SessionRepository` or `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository`) to interact with your repository and inject the instance that was created by Spring Session configuration and registered as a bean in the application context, rather that instantiating `JdbcOperationsSessionRepository` yourself.

There are basically two ways you can inject a `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository` instance - either to inject and use raw type, or parameterized (respecting the original contract of `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<S extends Session>`).

Raw type approach:

```
class RawConsumer {

    @Autowired
    private FindByIndexNameSessionRepository sessionRepository;

    void consume() {
        Session session = (Session) this.sessionRepository.createSession();
        session.setAttribute("test", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        this.sessionRepository.save(session);
    }

}
```

Parameterized type approach:

```
class ParameterizedConsumer<S extends Session> {

    @Autowired
    private FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<S> sessionRepository;

    void consume() {
        S session = this.sessionRepository.createSession();
        session.setAttribute("test", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        this.sessionRepository.save(session);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Vedran Pavić, you also replied my post at Gitter channel. The solution really help but I still confusing between FindByIndexNameSessionRepository and JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.

After I successful saved the session in database, how come there are two records for each each session?

Comment: `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository` is Spring Session's session repository API, and `JdbcOperationsSessionRepository` is its JDBC backed implementation and only one of the implementations provided by Spring Session. You should always consume an API through its contract (i.e. the interface in this case) rather than interact directly with the implementation. Your question on _two records_ is unclear to me, I'd recommend you to try reach us on Spring Session's Gitter channel for such questions.

Comment: Is it best to use SessionRepository over FindByIndexNameSessionRepository? Plus what would the @Bean method look like? Finally is it bad to inject  a raw type of FindByIndexNameSessionRepository?